# HowTo Dynamic ToolTip or changing tooltip on one button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a small VB winforms app with a forward and back button. These two buttons allow you to cycle through numerous "pages". I would like to display the next and previous page title in tooltips when the mouse hovers over the buttons(arrows).

Example, when hovering over the left arrow button, I would like to display the name previous page.
So page 1 is applications, page 2 is emails, page 3 is pdf documents etc...

I added the tooltip property from the toolbox in Visual Studios, but it only allows me to type a single item as opposed to scrolling through my list of pages and determining what the previous page name is and displaying it.

The page or form itselt doesn't change, and neither do the buttons, just a panel contained inside the form has the "pages" that change, so I need to be able to write a function that figures out which page is previous and which page is next on the fly when mousehovers the buttons in question... Then returns the data so I can display it in the tooltip.

Better Question;
How can I pass any variable into a tooltip instead of setting it as a property.

Comment: Well, I have only tried the built in tooltip. Putting my pages into a list and cycling through the list for the text to be displayed wouldn't be an issue... It would just be; how do I call the function that I create and most importantly, how do I return the "page" text into a value I can pass into the tooltip text. 

Or better yet, how can I pass any variable into a tooltip instead of setting it as a property. 

I think I am making this harder than it is...

Comment: Post the code you have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given a tooltip named `ToolTip1`, then you can set variable text to a control, like this:

```
Dim myToolTipText = "Dummy text"
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.Button1, myToolTipText)
```

Comment: Perfect Karl !!!!
That is exaclty what I am looking for. Sorry I couldn't post the code, I hadn't written any yet. I just knew what I wanted and not quite how to get there and sir, you got me there. TY 
P.S. I am still building rep points here. I WILL come back and vote this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to assign the button's text to the tooltip title at runtime. I used the following code:

```vb
Private Sub ToolTip1_Popup(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PopupEventArgs) _ 
   Handles ToolTip1.Popup
        ToolTip1.ToolTipTitle = e.AssociatedControl.Text
End Sub
```